# Ubuntu Kernel 5.7.1

Tags: upgrade, kernel, 20.04

My new laptop came with Ubuntu 20.04 (Kernel 5.4). I get occasional
notifications that Kernel 5.7.1 is available, but it doesn't appear as an option when I update my software. What is the story here?

Comment: Do you mean Desktop Notifications? Or some other kind of notification? Smells like some possible OEM-specific or based-upon-Ubuntu (Kali, Mint, Pop!) feature that has not propagated upstream to Ubuntu. Or maybe it's malware.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 currently uses the 5.4 kernel, and it's the only supported kernel. Your message shows you have non-Canonical/Ubuntu sources on your system, as 5.7 is only a *test* kernel in the Ubuntu world, and currently unsupported (ie. *test* kernels you support & upgrade yourself)

Comment: I mean a box opens on my desktop and says that 5.7.1 is now available.  When I update my software through the Software Updater, it never mentions 5.7.1.  I purchased my laptop from Zareason with Ubuntu 18.04 preinstalled.  I later used the Software Updater to upgrade to 20.04. If I have an OEM-specific version how do I get the official version installed? I'm not afraid to wipe out my disk and reinstall the official version. Where would I download the official 20.04 version.  Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be getting any notifications from Ubuntu about kernel versions that aren't yet available for your version of Ubuntu.

Ubuntu does not ship a "bleeding edge" kernel because more testing is required before it is considered stable enough for Ubuntu.  It's generally not wise to use the most recent kernel version unless you are testing.

When mainstream updates to the kernel are available, the kernel will be updated through regular updates from the software center or `apt`.